# How do I get lighttpd access log to stdout?

Tags: lighttpd, stdout

I am running `lighttpd` in a docker container on Ubuntu (as a service that must always be up in my `traefik` setup). My `docker-compose.yml` contains:

```
  lighttpd:
    image: sebp/lighttpd
    container_name: lighttpd
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /srv/docker/traefik/lighttpd/etc/lighttpd.conf:/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
      - /srv/docker/traefik/lighttpd/log/error.log:/var/log/lighttpd/error.log
      - /srv/docker/traefik/lighttpd/log/access.log:/var/log/lighttpd/access.log
      - /var/www/miniserver/html/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80"
    tty: true
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.lighttpd.rule=Host(`foo.rna.nl`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.lighttpd.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.lighttpd.tls=false"
    networks:
      - proxy
```

`lighttpd` works, serves me `index.html`, but:

```
# docker logs lighttpd
2022-10-29 12:13:55: (server.c.1568) server started (lighttpd/1.4.64)
```

I get the startup message, but nothing else. When I direct access log to a file, I get access log entries there:

```
172.26.0.2 foo.rna.nl - [29/Oct/2022:11:53:02 +0000] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 37 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15"
```

How do I direct `lighttpd`'s access log to stdout? I tried both of these:

```
accesslog.filename = "/proc/self/fd/1"
accesslog.filename = "/dev/stdout"
```

My full `lighttpd.conf`:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_indexfile",
    "mod_access",
    "mod_alias",
    "mod_redirect",
    "mod_accesslog",
)

server.document-root = "/var/www/html" 
#server.errorlog = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.port = 80

mimetype.assign = (
  ".html" => "text/html", 
  ".txt" => "text/plain",
  ".jpg" => "image/jpeg",
  ".png" => "image/png" 
)

accesslog.filename = "/proc/self/fd/1"
#accesslog.filename = "/dev/stdout"
#accesslog.filename = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Lighttpd must close *stdout* when it start up, so you can't send output there, but you *can* send access logs to *stderr*:

```
accesslog.filename = "/dev/fd/2"
```

(Or `/proc/self/fd/2` if you prefer.)

If you really want logs on *stdout* instead of *stderr*, you can perform some fd redirection tricks as shown [here](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/8382):

1. Redirect a new fd to the original stdout:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   exec 3>&1
   lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
   ```
2. Point the access log at the new fd:

   ```
   accesslog.filename = "/dev/fd/3"
   ```

This requires overriding the existing container startup command with a shell script.

Comment: I tried using fd2 for `accesslog.filename` and that works, thanks. Redirection means I must change the default startup of the `lighttpd` container, maybe try that later because I don't know how to easily do that using `docker compose`.